# Replacing Javascript Array elements with element from other array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have the following simple code, working with Java Array

```
  var fruits = [["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"]];
  var names  =  ["Adam", "Emma", "Joe", "David"];                
  var newArray=[];

  for (var i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++){      
    newArray[i] = fruits[0];    // Copy fruits[] into newArray[] 
    newArray[i][1] = names[i];  // Then replace the 2nd element with names[]    
  }
```

The desire outcome is this...

```
newArray[0] = ["Banana", "Adam" , "Apple", "Mango"]
newArray[1] = ["Banana", "Emma" , "Apple", "Mango"]
newArray[2] = ["Banana", "Joe"  , "Apple", "Mango"]
newArray[3] = ["Banana", "David", "Apple", "Mango"]
```

However I get this final result and can't work out why...

```
newArray[0] = ["Banana", "David" , "Apple", "Mango"]
newArray[1] = ["Banana", "David" , "Apple", "Mango"]
newArray[2] = ["Banana", "David" , "Apple", "Mango"]
newArray[3] = ["Banana", "David" , "Apple", "Mango"]
```

I'm only very new to JS so figure this could be down to something simple but at stage it's a brick wall that can't be pass. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Java is not JavaScript - it's important to be clear about the distinction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is:

```
newArray[i] = fruits[0];    // Copy fruits[] into newArray[]
```

`newArray[i]` is not a *copy* of the first item in `fruits` - rather, it's just *another reference* to the same object in memory. So, when you change `newArray[i]`, you also change `fruits[0]`, and you also change any other variables which hold the same reference to `fruits[0]` - that is, *every* item in `newArray`.

Explicitly clone `fruits[0]` on each iteration instead:

```js
var fruits = [
  ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"]
];
var names = ["Adam", "Emma", "Joe", "David"];
var newArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  newArray[i] = [...fruits[0]];
  newArray[i][1] = names[i];
}
console.log(newArray);
```

`[...fruits[0]]` is spread syntax - it creates a shallow copy of `fruits[0]`.

You might consider using `.map` instead though, `.map` is a bit more appropriate when you're creating a new array from every element of another:

```js
var fruits = [
  ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"]
];
var names = ["Adam", "Emma", "Joe", "David"];

const newArray = names.map((name) => {
  const arr = [...fruits[0]];
  arr[1] = name;
  return arr;
});
console.log(newArray);
```

Alternatively, without spread, use `slice`:

```js
var fruits = [
  ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"]
];
var names = ["Adam", "Emma", "Joe", "David"];

const newArray = names.map((name) => {
  const arr = fruits[0].slice();
  arr[1] = name;
  return arr;
});
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, unfortunately [...fruits[0]] gives off syntax error at my, I should note I'm running this through Google Apps JavaScript so perhaps spread syntax is not yet supported.

Comment: You should make it clear what limitations you have in your question. You can use `slice` instead of spread syntax, see edit (or you can use Babel to transpile down to ES5 automatically, allowing you to write in the latest and greatest version of the language, it's great with larger projects)

Comment: I ended up using your example but fruits[0].slice() instead of [...fruits[0]]